# Как правильно сделать объявление?

Tags: стилистика

Бесит в торговых центрах громкое объявление: "Сотрудника отдела (название отдела) просьба подойти к (куда следует подойти)". Это такое клише? Как правильно должно быть сделано такое объявление?

Comment: Вы бы сами сперва грамотно научились писать и излагать свои мысли, а потом уже бесились от чужих ошибок. Во-первых, слово "выбешивает" - не литературное, во-вторых, "клише" пишется через И.

Answer (score 1):

Либо "Сотрудника просят", либо "Сотруднику — просьба".

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, тут причина в том, что главной задачей этого объявления является привлечение внимания данного сотрудника отдела, именно поэтому его фамилия и данные выносятся на первый план.